# Change UISegmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex doesn't change the selected index

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to create a toggle button in a navigation bar in iOS5 with UISegmentControl. The problem I'm having is that setSelectedSegmentIndex isn't persistent, i.e. when the users clicks one of the segments, it's action gets called but it isn't set as selected. My current code looks like this:

```
// In viewDidLoad
toolSegment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
                                        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"ToolPenIcon.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"TextIcon.png"],
                                         nil]];
[toolSegment addTarget:self action:@selector(changeMode:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
toolSegment.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 85, 30);
toolSegment.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBezeled;
toolSegment.momentary = YES;    
[toolSegment setSelectedSegmentIndex:1];    
UIBarButtonItem *segmentBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:toolSegment];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = segmentBarItem;

self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];   

- (void)changeMode:(id)sender
{    
    UISegmentedControl * control = (UISegmentedControl*)sender;

    if (control.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Print");
        [toolSegment setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];    
    } else {
         // Should change the selected index.             
         [toolSegment setSelectedSegmentIndex:1];

        [pageView changeToText];
        if (pageView.canvas.image != nil) {
            [self createNewPage];
        }
        writing = YES;
    }    
}
```

Any tips on what I might be doing wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: Any particular reason why you set  the control to momentary mode? Do you want to allow the user to select multiple things? If not, set it to NO and the selected index should work.

Comment: Glad to hear that. I made the comment an answer, so you can accept it and help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want the control to be in `momentary` mode as this would allow multi selection. Set `momentary` to `NO`.